# How can I turn the array of numbers into a list that only appears when the plus icon is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

I have returned an array of results and turned it into an average, but below the average, I wish to reveal each individual test result of the student when the grey plus icon is clicked.
like the link below shows.

https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/f-1/735fae21-9b8d-4431-8978-5098a2217fd2/part4.webm

any help is appreciated

```
const apiInfo = $('.info');
const avg = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0) / arr.length;

const nameSeachInput = $('#nameSearch');
nameSeachInput.on('input',
  function() {
    apiInfo.empty();  

    allStudents.filter(student => student.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(this.value.toLowerCase()) || student.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(this.value.toLowerCase())).forEach(student => {
      if (student.id.includes('')) {
        renderStudentInfo(student, apiInfo);
      }
    });
  });
let allStudents;  

const renderStudentInfo = (student, $target) => {
  const fullName = student.firstName + ' ' + student.lastName,
    average = avg(student.grades.map(grade => parseInt(grade, 10)));
  $target.append($(`
    <div class="infoB">
      <img class="pPic float-left m-3"
        src="${student.pic}" alt="profile pic" />
      <h4 class="title">${fullName}<h4>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Email: ${student.email}</p>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Comapny: ${student.company}</p>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Skill: ${student.skill}</p>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Average: ${average.toFixed(2)}%</p>
      <p class="mb-1 d-none" id="stats"> ${student.grades}%<p>
      <a href=# id="plus"><i class="mb-5 fa fa-plus float-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  `));
};

$( "#plus" ).click(function() {
  $( '#stats' ).toggleClass( "d-none" );
});

const init = () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students',
    method: 'GET',
  }).then(({
    students
  }) => {
    allStudents = students; 
    students.forEach((student) => {
      if (student.id.includes('')) {
        renderStudentInfo(student, apiInfo);
      }
    });
  });
}

init();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="input mt-5 mx-5">
      <input
        id="nameSearch"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Search by name"
        aria-label="Search by name"
        aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="input mb-0 mt-2 mx-5">
      <input
        id="tagSearch"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Search tags"
        aria-label="Search tags"
        aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="container mt-0">
      <div class="info card scroll shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded"></div>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(243, 240, 240);
}

img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid rgb(156, 148, 148) 1px;
    min-width: 130px;
}

.infoB{
    border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
}

.stats{
    color: grey;
    margin-left: 175px;
}

.title{
    font-size: 50px;
}

.card {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.scroll {
    max-height: 575px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.fa-plus{
    color: grey;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Which part isn't working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: You might want to read [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992), which should make it easier for people to test.

Comment: Hey Sorry I'm new to using stack overflow! the line of code 
<p class="mb-1 d-none" id="stats"> ${student.grades}%<p>
 I want to toggle the class d-none, on and off, and separate the array of numbers into a list with the name of the test in front of each result like the video in the link shows.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, but the simplest way would be to have the individual numbers in a container that you show/hide every time the plus icon is clicked. You may also want to swap the plus icon image for a minus icon on each toggle.

I've implemented a basic version here: https://jsfiddle.net/r63ctej0/

Essentially, in the above implementation, I've put the numbers in a `<ul>` tag and I give this list an id `{fullName}_numbers` so that each card has a unique id.

Then I create a `toggleNumbers(id)` function that takes that id and switches its display state.

Lastly, I added `onclick=toggleName('{fullName}_numbers')` to the plus icon